# BASH Array behavior different when using Command Substitution

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```bsh
melon@machine: ~/$ cat /tmp/test.json 
[
    "One Entry Here",
    "Two Entry Here",
    "Three Entry Here",
    "Four Entry Here"
]
melon@machine: ~/$ jq -sr '.[]|  @sh' /tmp/test.json
'One Entry Here' 'Two Entry Here' 'Three Entry Here' 'Four Entry Here'
melon@machine: ~/$ BANANA=( 'One Entry Here' 'Two Entry Here' 'Three Entry Here' 'Four Entry Here' )
melon@machine: ~/$ echo ${BANANA[1]}
Two Entry Here
```

The above shows the expected behavior, and shows me manually setting `$BANANA` to the output of the `jq` command.

This behavior changes if the variable uses command substitution instead:

```bsh
melon@machine: ~/$ BANANA=( $(jq -sjr '.[]|  @sh' /tmp/test.json) )
melon@machine: ~/$ echo ${BANANA[1]}

melon@machine: ~/$ echo ${BANANA[0]}
'One Entry Here' 'Two Entry Here' 'Three Entry Here' 'Four Entry Here'
```

---

While it is true that I am trying to convert a JSON array into a BASH array to iterate over, and there are other suggested methods, my question is **Why is the behavior different here when using command substitution, and is there anything that I can do to have the command substitution behave like when I manually copy and paste the `jq` output into the variable myself?**

---

- `GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
- `GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

```bsh
melon@machine: ~/$ mapfile -t BANANA < <(jq '.[]' /tmp/test.json)
melon@machine: ~/$ echo ${BANANA[0]}
"One Entry Here"
melon@machine: ~/$ echo ${BANANA[1]}
"Two Entry Here"
```

`mapfile` works, but I'm still curious about the difference when using command substitution.

Even after adding the `-j` flag to `jq` to suppress ending newline, the results are the same.

Comment: I'm puzzled by your results - I would expect `BANANA[0]` to be `'One` and `BANANA[1]` to be `Entry` i.e. the the (unquoted) command substitution would be split on whitespace. Your results are more consistent with a quoted command substitution (or with an empty or unset `IFS`)

Comment: I've switched to focus on how `jq` may be causing the difference, and it seems that it may be providing a newline at the end of the output, which may be causing a difference.  Simply adding `-j` flag to suppress the  newline doesn't seem to help. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: If your end goal is to get the JSON elements into a bash array, then I'd suggest something like `mapfile -t BANANA < <(jq -r '.[]' /tmp/test.json)`

Comment: Thank you, originally when trying `mapfile`, I was using the same `jq` flags and now that I've adjusted those, `mapfile` does work.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) 
your [script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Comment: I'm familiar with PATH and many of the variables used in BASH in Linux.  I am having a hard time understanding what this suggestion has to do with the question.  If there is something I am missing, please let me know.

Comment: I think as @steeldriver suggested, you must have set `IFS=$'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do one of:

```bsh
IFS=$'\t' read -ra banana < <(jq -sr '.[] | @tsv' test.json)'
```

which gives the expected:

```bsh
$ declare -p banana
declare -a banana=([0]="One Entry Here" [1]="Two Entry Here" [2]="Three Entry Here" [3]="Four Entry Here")'
```

Or use `declare` which is kind of like `eval` but just for variable assignments:

```bsh
declare -a "banana=($(jq -sr '.[] | @sh' test.json))"
```

This forces the shell to do a 2nd round of expansions so that the quotes emitted by jq will be process properly by the shell. Otherwise you get:

```bsh
$ banana=($(jq -sr '.[] | @sh' test.json))
$ declare -p banana
declare -a banana=([0]="'One" [1]="Entry" [2]="Here'" [3]="'Two" [4]="Entry" [5]="Here'" [6]="'Three" [7]="Entry" [8]="Here'" [9]="'Four" [10]="Entry" [11]="Here'")
```

or

```bsh
$ banana=("$(jq -sr '.[] | @sh' test.json)")
$ declare -p banana
declare -a banana=([0]="'One Entry Here' 'Two Entry Here' 'Three Entry Here' 'Four Entry Here'")
```

Comment: Thanks.  This has a lot of good information and is helpful to get the JSON array into BASH, but I'm still very curious about the difference in behavior as I described.